# Are there side effects of listening to binaural sounds?

Tags: mental-health, brain, meditation, soundwaves

I have started listening to binaural sounds (left side wave of 89.75hz, right side wave of 85.25hz) for meditation every day for 10 to 15 mins in morning. I feel calm, relaxed and focused after that.

I wanted to know, are there any side effects of listening to this ? Like can I get health problems or brain problems or tumor or cancer or anything damaging to body?

Would be thankful if anyone shares any knowledge on this.

Comment: What has your research found so far?

Comment: A couple of possibly related questions from psychology SE and skeptics SE: [Is there scientific evidence on the benefits of binaural beats?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8371), [Can “binaural beats” alter your state of consciousness?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/18694)